# Virtual Functions can set publicdata members of base class?

Tags: c++, function, virtual

setPosition(3,4) works in method foo() but not in virtual draw method of derived 
Rectangle class.  Is this not a feature in C++? Thank you.

```
class Shape
{
public:
       int posX, posY;
public:
    virtual void draw() const = 0;
    void setPosition(int pX, int pY)
    {
        posX = pX;
        posY = pY;
    }
};

class Rectangle : public Shape
{
public:
    virtual void draw() const
    { 
        cout << "Drawing rectangle at " << posX << "  "
           << posY << endl;
            setPosition(3,4);
    }
    void foo()
    {
        setPosition(3,4);
    }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call a non-`const` method from a `const` method as that would not leave the object unchanged.

If `draw` needs to call `setPosition` and hence change the `Rectangle`, then it cannot be declared `const`.